# error "column ambiguously defined" with column

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the SQL join query to list all the records of the columns: dname,ename and location. when I include the column "location", it's throwing an error: "column ambiguously defined"

```
SQL> select dname,ename,location from emp e join dept d on d.deptno=e.deptno;
```

Comment: location is present in both tables (emp and dept). So add table alias (if you want location from emp put e.location otherwise d.location)

Comment: so simple... super thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of `location` is present in tables (`emp`, `dept`) so you need table alise (`e` or `d`) to explicit define the columns (`d.dname, e.ename, e.location`) where it comes from.

```
select d.dname, e.ename, e.location 
from emp e join 
     dept d 
     on d.deptno = e.deptno;
```

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you have more than one table in a query, qualify all column references!  This is just a good habit that prevents problems.

When doing so, use table aliases that are abbreviations for the tables being referenced.  So, I'm guessing this is what your query intends:

```
select d.dname, e.ename, e.location
from emp e join
     dept d
     on d.deptno = e.deptno;
```

Answer (score 0):

you must specify a table name and field specifier if you have using the data table 2 with the same column name
ex: "select p.productName from products p inner join orders o on p.proID = o.proID"
list column of products table is: proID, proName, proPrice
and list column of orders table is: proID, oid, proName, proPrice.
i hope this help to description to you!